# Cross-compiling OpenGL / glew on linux for windows

Tags: opengl, linker, cross-compiling, undefined-reference, glew

I'm trying to cross-compile a small test opengl/glew program and I get linker errors from undefined references.

```
$ /usr/bin/i486-mingw32-g++ -I/usr/i486-mingw32/include -L/usr/i486-mingw32/lib/ -lglfw -lglew32 -lopengl32 main.cc
/tmp/cct8OpVh.o:main.cc:(.text+0x50): undefined reference to `glfwInit'
/tmp/cct8OpVh.o:main.cc:(.text+0xa6): undefined reference to `glfwOpenWindowHint'
...
```

The same code does work when compiling for linux:

```
$ g++ -I/usr/include -L/usr/lib/ -lglfw -lGLEW -lGL main.cc
```

One thing that caught my eye is that every exported symbol from cross-compiled libraries has an extra underscore prefix:

```
$ nm /usr/lib/libglfw.a | grep glfwInit$
00000000 T glfwInit

$ /usr/i486-mingw32/bin/nm /usr/i486-mingw32/lib/libglfw.a | grep glfwInit$
00000000 T _glfwInit
```

This seems to be a common thing since even libstdc++.a shares this property, but why is my cross-compiler linker then looking for non-underscore symbols?

Running arch with following packages (local means AUR):

```
community/mingw32-binutils 2.23.1-3
community/mingw32-gcc 4.7.2-1
local/mingw32-glew 1.9.0-1
local/mingw32-glfw 2.7.7-1
community/mingw32-pthreads 2.9.1-1
community/mingw32-runtime 3.20-4
community/mingw32-w32api 3.17-1
```

### EDIT

After playing out with both pkg-config and watching glfw recompile and test itself, I came up with the following magic that seems to work, at least I'm compiling:

```
 /usr/bin/i486-mingw32-g++ -I/usr/i486-mingw32/include -L/usr/i486-mingw32/lib -mwindows main.cc -lglew32 /usr/i486-mingw32/lib/libglfw.a /usr/i486-mingw32/lib/libopengl32.a -static-libgcc
```

There are few questions though:

- What is the difference between linking with -l and without?
- Why do I need to use -l with glew and cannot with glfw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem and, in case someone ever runs into similar situation hope this helps you.

- There are two versions of glew32 -library in my system, glew32.a and glew32.dll.a.

  - glew32.a does not allow for using --static, glew32.dll.a does.

The two commands which compile succesfully, only first of which I've run are:

```
/usr/bin/i486-mingw32-g++ -I/usr/i486-mingw32/include -L/usr/i486-mingw32/lib main.cc -lglew32.dll -lglfw -lopengl32 --static
/usr/bin/i486-mingw32-g++ -I/usr/i486-mingw32/include -L/usr/i486-mingw32/lib main.cc -lglew32 -lglfw -lopengl32
```

Looking at my old compiling attempts, the problem was wrong order of libraries and that main.cc was after the libraries.

Answer (score 2):

There is a program, called pkg-config that helps you to configure your compiler. See the manual pages for usage information, but, for this case, its output is:

> -mwin32 -I/usr/i486-mingw32/include -L/usr/i486-mingw32/lib -lglfw -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lm -s -mwindows -e _mainCRTStartup

Try to compile with this, I guess it will work.

Comment: While this wasn't the answer, it did point me to right tools to get me forward. See edit if you happen to be able to help me further.